# How Does a .feature File get found by Cucumber When Cucumber is Run?

Tags: cucumber, editor

In cucumber, after a new project directory is made and a .feature file is created and saved in an editor, how does the File get found by Cucumber When Cucumber is Run? Is the file exported manually into Cucumber or the tool scans the whole system automatically mapping itself to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Cucumber will load all files in the 'features' folder in the root directory (recursively).

If you want to use a different location you can run Cucumber with the command 'cucumber myfolder' which will look for features in a folder called myfolder in the project root.

---

It gets a bit more complicated when using subdirectories for features -> From this site (copied here for the record) - http://makandracards.com/makandra/4971-how-to-organize-and-execute-cucumber-features-e-g-in-subdirectories

By default, cucumber loads all *.rb files it can find (recursively) within the directory you passed as argument to cucumber.

```
$ cucumber # defaults to directory "features"
$ cucumber features
$ cucumber my/custom/features/dir
```

So, if you would like to organize features in subdirectories, you won't have any problems when running the whole test-suite. Cucumber will automatically load and run features in subdirectories, too.

However, running features in subdirectories does not work out of the box. The reason for this is that cucumber will look for your step definitions and support files within the subdirectory.

What you can do now is to either provide all needed support files and step definitions also within the subdirectories (not practicable) OR use the -r command line argument when running the subdirectory features:

```
cucumber -r features
```

Comment: Thanks alannichols. For clarity, you are saying that the .features file created in editor must be saved in in the 'features' folder in the root directory? This way cucumber will by default, look into that folder when it is run. Is this right? Is it this the same procedure for finding step definitions? Would cucumber, by default, look for the .rb file in the "feature/step_definitions" directory?

Comment: That's right about the feature files.  For step definitions, cucumber loads every .rb file in the features folder, so anywhere in there will be fine.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks alannichols, it does. Very helpful. May I please ask, what editor do you use for Cucumber? I am considering Eclipse. Will it do the job well?

Comment: I use rubymine for all of my ruby work.  I use sublime for plain text stuff.  If the answer is ok please mark it as answered and it'll be closed off :)  Eclipse is a java IDE if I recall correctly, it should work but you might want to pick something more suitable for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

In your testrunner class you can specify the path to where your feature files are locate.

Comment: Thanks Anand. Could you please give an example, for clarity? Thanks

Comment: Assuming you already have a testrunner class file, you can specify a path for the feature. features = "TestScenarios/specifiedPathName"

Comment: What editor do you use for your plain text file, Anand?